# Maximum number of terms of a polynomial of degree n and p indeterminates

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to figure out the maximum number of terms a polynomial have.
This polynomial f has p indeterminates, the degree is maximum n and its quotients belong to an arbitrary field K.

It would look something like this: [image: polynomial]

Let (i_1, i_2, ... , i_p) be the powers of the indeterminates 
and C(n,k) = n! / ( k! (n-k)! ) 
 
and A(n,k) = n! / (n-k)!

I know that:
The number of terms of degree 0 is 1: 
(0,0,...,0)

The number of terms of degree 1 is p: 
(1,0,0,...,0), (0,1,0,0,...,0), ... , (0,0,...,0,1)

The number of terms of degree 2 is p + C(p,2):
(2,0,0,...,0), (0,2,0,0,...,0), ... , (0,0,...,0,2) 
and
(1,1,0,0,...,0), (1,0,1,0,0,...0), ... , (1,0,0,...,0,1), 
(0,1,1,0,0,...,0), (0,1,0,1,0,0,...,0), ... ,(0,0,...,0,1,1)

The number of terms of degree 3 is p + A(p,2) (or 2*C(n,2)) + C(n,3):
(3,0,0,...,0), (0,3,0,0,...,0), ... , (0,0,...,0,3) 
and
(2,1,0,0,...,0), (2,0,1,0,0,...0), ... , (2,0,0,...,0,1), 
(0,2,1,0,0,...,0), (0,2,0,1,0,0,...,0), ... ,(0,0,...,0,2,1)
(1,2,0,0,...,0), (1,0,2,0,0,...0), ... , (1,0,0,...,0,2), 
(0,1,2,0,0,...,0), (0,1,0,2,0,0,...,0), ... ,(0,0,...,0,1,2)
and 
(1,1,1,0,0,...,0), (1,1,0,1,0,0,...0), ... , (1,1,0,0,...,0,1), 
(0,1,1,1,0,0,...,0), (0,1,1,0,1,0,0,...,0), ... ,(0,0,...,0,1,1,1)

The number of terms of degree 4 is p + A(p,2) + C(p,2) + C(p,4):
4 = 4
4 = 3 + 1 (also 4 = 1 + 3)
4 = 2 + 2
4 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1

The number of terms of degree 5 is p + A(p,2) + A(p,2) + A(p,3) + A(p,4) + C(p,5):

5 = 5
5 = 4 + 1 (also 5 = 1 + 4)
5 = 3 + 2 (also 5 = 2 + 3)
5 = 3 + 1 + 1 (also 1 + 3 + 1 also 1 + 1 + 3)
5 = 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 (also 1 + 2 + 1 + 1 also 1 + 1 + 2 + 1 also 1 + 1 + 1 + 2)
5 = 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1

By the number of terms of degree 6 it gets too messy.

Basically I'm asking if the ring of polynomials of degree maximum n and p indeterminates is isomorphic with the field K to a power m, and what that power m is.
I would appreciate if someone could give me a hint or a formula.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You can add one extra dummy variable and then assume that the degree of each term in your polynomial is exactly $n$. (removing the dummy variable gives you your original polynomial back).

Another hint: If you want to partition integer $n$ into $k$ non-negative integer parts, this is the same as partitioning $(n+k)$ into $k$ positive integer parts. The "sticks and stones" construction allows you to do this: How many ways can you place $k-1$ identical sticks in between $(n+k)$ stones so that no two sticks are in the same position so that the stones are split into $k$ consecutive groups of positive size?

Answer: (In case you don't want to follow the hints): ${n+p} \choose p$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.


I understood that the number of (i1, ... , ip) where i1+...+ip = n is C(n+p, p).


But what about when i1+...ip < n ?